# optimizing finding neighbors in Z^3

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have an array of points in Z^3 (integer 3-tuples).

**How can I quickly determine the neighbors for every point?** Where a neighbor is a point exactly one unit distance away (Euclidean metric).

For example, say the array is:

`{ {0,0,0}, {0,0,1}, {1,1,1} }`

then `{0,0,0}` and `{0,0,1}` are neighbors and `{1,1,1}` has no neighbors.

Currently, I'm sorting all points lexicographicaly in a `std::vector` and then using `std::lower_bound` to search for neighbors (6 binary searches). This is significantly faster than using `std::unordered_map` for my test data.

Is there another approach that could be faster? (Note that I cannot use a regular grid as the points may be rather far apart. Also note: since there was some confusion below, this is a question regarding optimization, not correctness. The implementation I suggested above is trivial.)

For a test data set, assume a voxelized sphere with radius 256.

Comment: lexicographic order shouldn't work ... idk, I din't think too much about it, but at my first glance lexicographic order misses a lot of cases.

Comment: @dyz - so (6,1,0) and (3,3,2) are neighbors?

Comment: @bolov You sort lexicographically and then do a binary search. It's a trivial approach and it works.

Comment: ok found a simple case where lexicographic order and lower_bound fails: `{2 2 2} {2 2 3} {2 2 4} {3 2 2}`. In relation to `{2 2 2}`: there is non-neighbor `{2 2 4}` between him and a neighbor {3 2 2}

Comment: @bolov That's not what I'm doing.

Comment: @Taylor well... what are you doing?

Comment: @bolov I said above: using `lower_bound` which is a binary search. I search for the 6 potential neighbors of a given point.

Comment: @Taylor, please address to what bolov stated. He took 4 points `{2 2 2} {2 2 3} {2 2 4} {3 2 2}` in lexicographically sorted order and proved that there are neighbours `{2 2 2}` and `{3 2 2}` which are separated by non-neighbour `{2 2 4}`. This proves that `lower_bound` won't work, since the sorting does not group the neighbourds together. If there is an error in the above logic, please address that, instead of saying "*That's not what I'm doing*". I'm pretty sure that most of us had the same thought process as **bolov**

Comment: This is either an algorithm question or a C++ question. If you know the algorithm that describes a small-complexity process for doing this, but you don't know how to implement some part of it in C++, then show what you've already implemented, and describe exactly what's missing. If you don't even know what the algorithm should be -- which is what this sounds like -- then this has nothing to do with C++. You need to figure out what the algorithm is, first. Otherwise trying to see if this library function will work, or that library function will work, is a waste of time.

Comment: ohh, I think you meant for each point you do 6 separate searches for each possible neighbor.

Comment: I mean if you want to sacrifice a lot of space and do data replication you can create 3 vectors, each sorted on a different value, then just step up and down in each vector. This has tons of drawbacks, but it should let you read very quickly.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I've tried to clarify above. This question is about optimization, not correctness.

Comment: @bolov Yes, 6 separate binary searches. Sorry, I thought it was obvious.

Answer (score 1):

> Note that I cannot use a regular grid as the points may be rather far
>   apart

Teapot in stadium problem can be solved by multi-level grid or some octa-tree maybe. Each node containing 1/8 volume of its parent. Since everything is integer, you can probably do this by chars instead of integers. They'd only need to travel up once in a tree and check neighbor children, if empty, go up twice, check neighbor parents. This should be significantly faster(maybe only 64 nodes for closest neighbors) than checking whole array(how many?). I guess only 64 nodes are enough because by checking only x0+1,y0+1,z0+1 for each point, you don't need to check x0-1, y0-1, z0-1 since it duplicates same things. So, including itself and neighbors (all parents) it is 8x8=64 nodes for closest neighbors(even diagonals, you can ommit them ofcourse) maybe you can ommit diagonal ones and check only 3x8=24 nodes.

When there is no point in a node, don't build that node. When there is, then simply have a char value 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 that shows its (z-index) from point of view of its parent.

There can be also a cache for stationary points, probably to reduce number of compute when scene is needed to be recomputed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an O(N*log(N)) solution:

1. Sort the vector lexicographically.
2. Iterate over the vector to find which items are exactly one-unit distant from their predecessor in the vector.  i.e.

   `bool pointsAreNeighbors = (abs(item[0]-prevItem[0])+abs(item[1]-prevItem[1])+abs(item[2]-prevItem[2])==1);`

   If the above expression is calculated as true, insert `item` (and its predecessor `prevItem`) as a key/value pair, into a `std::map` (or similar key/value based data structure), as they are part of your result-set.
3. Sort the vector lexicographically again, except this time using a custom sort-functor such that the middle-values in each item are considered the lowest-order sub-sorting criterion (rather than the last-values).
4. Repeat step 2,
5. Sort the vector lexicographically again, except this time using a custom sort-functor such that the first-values in each item are considered the lowest-order sub-sorting criterion (rather than the last-values or middle-values).
6. Repeat step 2.
7. At this point, your result-set should contain all the neighbor-pairs.

Note: The final result set may contain some redundant pairs (e.g. it might contain both (A,B) and (B,A)) -- depending on your use-case, you may or may not want to filter those out afterwards, or alternatively add a bit of extra logic to step (2) that swaps key and value of any "out-of-order pair" before inserting it into the result-set.